# Oracle gateway to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, gateway

I create gateway in Oracle server to SQL Server, and then get records from Oracle to SQL Server through that gateway. The problem is the Chinese messy code show up when use the gateway. please refer below result:

```
select '测试測試' TEST from dual;
```

Returns:

```
TEST  
测试測試


select '测试測試' TEST from dual@MSSQLWAS;
```

Returns:

```
TEST 
????
```

*PS: "MSSQLWAS" is link name.*

- Oracle : 10g / OS: Linux / Gateway: 11g
- SQL Server 2008 R2 / OS: WINDOWS NT 6.1

Comment: did you try `select '测试測試' TEST ` on mssql ?

Comment: OH...no... I take it for granted. I never test it on MSSQL. It runs abnormal on MMSQL, I will investigate on the way. Do you have any experience for this issues? Thanks.

Comment: select N'测试測試' TEST.  The sql updated like this shows normal in MSSQL. But, it still can show [select N'测试測試' TEST from dual@MSSQLWAS;]   with normal in Oracle.